# How do I do 'dir /s /b' in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with three files and want the equivalent of `dir /s /b` in PowerShell. How do I do that?

For example, if the folder name is `temp3` and it contains three text files - `a.txt`. `b.txt`, and `c.txt`, doing

```
C:\temp3> dir /s /b
```

gives me

```
C:\temp3\a.txt
C:\temp3\b.txt
C:\temp3\c.txt
```

How do I get the *same* result in PowerShell?

Comment: dir -s -n   -- It's undocumented that -s is also recursive. -n gives just the name, but without the drive letter (if you can live with that)

Comment: Welcome to the SO freakshow;) I first had to find out what are these two flags. So /s means list files the recursive way and /b is just the files.

Answer (score 82):

If you are using Powershell as a shell (and not as a script processor), you can simply type:

```
cmd /r dir /s /b
```

The `/r` flag tells `cmd.exe` to run the command and exit. In other words, you'll end at the same execution context.

For many commands, `cmd /r` is better than dealing with Powershell object-oriented architecture.

Comment: I find great irony that the shortest way to write the command in powershell is just to shell-back to old `cmd.exe`.  PowerShell is a bloated, hulking mess.  DOS, for all its failings, is efficient.

Comment: @abelenky `gci -r | % FullName` seems pretty short and is arguably easier to remember than `dir` flags

Comment: @abelenky +1, additional property of caused by bloatedness - it's slow.

Comment: I've never seen `/R` and couldn't find in the option list of cmd until I saw this *Also, for compatibility reasons, `/X` is the same as /E:ON, `/Y` is the same as `/E:OFF` and `/R` is the same as `/C`.  Any other switches are ignored.* So it's better to use `/C` and `/K`

Comment: ... or cmd /c .. (the two last dots are for being able to write this stuff.

Comment: @abelenky DOS has been gone since Windows ME.

Comment: There is -NO- reason to use `cmd.exe` in PowerShell for this. `(Get-ChildItem -Recurse).FullName`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined

Comment: That's useful only if you don't care whether the file times are reproducible or not. They are in powershell, but the cmd.exe 'dir' hashes them according to when you run it and when the file was created/modified, using the most impractical DST conversions that Microsoft could think of.

Comment: I find the short command names and very short flags (in both DOS and Bash) are much easier to remember than the long equivalents in Powershell.

Comment: When the file/path names contain Unicode characters CMD will replace them (f.e. `∶` to `:`, and `∕` to `/`), ruining the whole sense of using a Unicode capable shell.

Answer (score 48):

You can use

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
gci -r | select -exp FullName
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
gci -r | % { $_.FullName }
gci -r | % FullName    # In recent PowerShell versions
```

(The long version is the first one and the one shortened using aliases and short parameter names is the second, if it's not obvious. In scripts I'd suggest using always the long version since it's much less likely to clash somewhere.)

Re-reading your question, if all you want to accomplish with `dir /s /b` is to output the full paths of the files in the current directory, then you can drop the `-Recurse` parameter here.

My advice to you, though: Don't use strings when you can help it. If you want to pass around files, then just take the `FileInfo` object you get from `Get-ChildItem`. The cmdlets know what to do with it. Using strings for things where objects work better just gets you into weird problems.

Comment: You can also do:

gci -r | select -expand fullname

Comment: @Johannes: it does work.  You using v2 final?  See http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/09/14/select-expandproperty-propertyname.aspx

Comment: Hm, no, to my shame I looked it up in v1 (I was at the only machine near me that still has v1). And I even read that blog post but didn't remember it.

Comment: You might also want to filter as well

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Where-Object { $_ -like "*.log" }

Comment: @aolszowka: It's faster to filter in `Get-ChildItem`, e.g. with `-Filter *.log`. Besides, that was not part of the question.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Joey You wrote `gci -r | % FullName    # In recent PowerShell versions`. Starting from which PowerShell  version can this notation be used ?

Answer (score 11):

This is equivalent:

```
(dir -r).FullName
```

Answer (score 11):

A variation of [Bob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195088/1485885) answer is to use a pipe for realtime output (having a better feedback in large directories):

```
dir -r | % FullName
```

Comment: Nice answer, I will use it in a new $profile function : `ls -r | % FullName | sls $($args[0])`

Answer (score 8):

Adding onto Joey's answer.  Starting in PowerShell 3.0, you can use the new `Foreach-Object` shorthand to get the `FullName` property.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Foreach-Object FullName
gci -r |% FullName
```

The difference is that you don't need to use curly braces (`{}`) or the `$_` variable if all you need is a property.

Comment: At last! The one true way to avoid spurious blank lines!

Comment: this seems the most intuitive answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just to enforce, what Joey said:

```
gci -r -filter *.log | % fullname
```

This works to find files like `dir /s/b *.log` does.

---

`(dir -r *.log).FullName` works as well

---

Execute this once in your powershell shell, to enable a `dirsb *.log` command:

```
function global:dirsb {
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$fileFilter)
    gci -r -filter $fileFilter | % fullname
}
```

or add it to your profile: `PS> notepad $profile`

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to permanently replace Powershell's dir alias (Get-ChildItem) with a call to cmd dir, for all future powershell windows you're going to open just do the following:

1. notepad $profile (from powershell window)
2. when file opens, insert the following rows and save:

   ```
   Remove-Item alias:\dir
   function dir($1, $2, $3, $4) {cmd /r dir $1 $2 $3 $4}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, the command-line to find files is `Get-ChildItem` that have aliases (`gci`,`ls`,`dir`).
In the `dir -?`, you can find the url explanation : [Get-ChildItem](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308)

Examples of commands:

`dir *.txt -s | select name,length`

`ls *.txt -s | select fullname`

Answer (score 0):

`CMD /r DIR \\\\URL /s` is VERY useful... PowerShell does not allow \\URL in `Get-ChildItem` alias ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working interactively with PowerShell shell instead of writing a script, you can just shell-back to old cmd.exe by typing `cmd` and enter. then you can run `dir /s /b` as old times.
Pay attention to the command line prompt to distinguish if you are in PS or CMD.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select FullName
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: This is identical to an existing answer

Answer (score 0):

To show files recursively (including hidden ones), I use :

```
$ ls -r -h | % fullname
```