# equivalent of (dir/b > files.txt) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dir

```
dir/b > files.txt
```

I guess it has to be done in PowerShell to preserve unicode signs.

Comment: [How do I do `dir /s /b` in PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1479663/995714)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name > files.txt
```

or shorter:

```
ls | % Name > files.txt
```

However, you can easily do the same in `cmd`:

```
cmd /u /c "dir /b > files.txt"
```

The `/u` switch tells `cmd` to write things redirected into files as Unicode.

Comment: PSH: ńóręąśóń -> ńóręąśóń CMD: ńóręąśóń -> ä˘r©Ą˘ä changing font does not work.

Comment: It looks ok on the screen, but not in the file.

Comment: Przemysław: Use `cmd /u` to start `cmd` if you want stuff redirected to files to use Unicode instead of following the legacy codepage.

Answer (score 18):

`Get-ChildItem` actually already has a flag for the equivalent of `dir /b`:

`Get-ChildItem -name` (or `dir -name`)

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that yet. I usually go the "Produce objects, project into something useful" route.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put:

```
dir -Name > files.txt
```

Comment: you should really add some reference or documentation for this or better explain it

Comment: Sorry, but the other posts seem to have not been provided with documentations either. Anyway, I can't get a proper documentation for my answer, but I use it as 'the equivalent of dir /b > files.txt' which works favorably.

Comment: So if everyone jumps off a bridge, that makes it ok for you to do it too? You should only care about the quality of your own work, not compare it to the others. We are providing technical solutions, which always by nature of the industry standard require some kind of explanation, elaboration and references in the least of the cases. Simple as that really, you don't want to do it, that's fine but don't expect your answer to receive quality attention or be received well in general. It was to help you, not a recrimination, take the constructive suggestion, don't fight or justify it.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and good intention, sir. However, it is not because I don't want to provide it, but it is by far the best I could provide. I've been searching for a proper documentation and, unfortunately, couldn't acquire one. Without one, the answers are merely hack at best, but hey, if I see everyone jumps off a bridge and it's the only way to get down there but somehow landed on their feet, then it's worth the shot. I would have only jumped a little differently, which in my opinion is more efficient. I'll provide a proper reference in the future if I get my hands into one.

Comment: I really hope that my comment didn't come across as snooty because that is the furthest from my intention to provide constructive feedback. But I will say, if you have a parachute or think you can land on your feet, by all means take the leap ;) Now all seriousness, it was meant to help you provide better information and instill sense of confidence in people following it, that's all and if you ever find it, come back and update your answer because people WILL come across it at some point, it would be great if they can learn from it. After all at some point you had to learn it yourself somehow.

Comment: `dir -?` couldn't find the help files on my computer but provided a link to https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6 which explains the `-Name` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

In PSH `dir` (which aliases `Get-ChildItem`) gives you objects (as noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536708/equivalent-of-dir-b-files-txt-in-powershell/5537132#5537132)), so you need to select what properties you want. Either with `Select-Object` (alias `select`) to create custom objects with a subset of the original object's properties (or additional properties can be added).

However in this can doing it at the format stage is probably simplest

```
dir | ft Name -HideTableHeaders | Out-File files.txt
```

(`ft` is `format-table`.)

If you want a different character encoding in `files.txt` (`out-file` will use UTF-16 by default) use the `-encoding` flag, you can also append:

```
dir | ft Name -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -append -encoding UTF8 files.txt
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Can you tell me why that code returns me an empty row between each item?

Comment: @NickRulez: "Works on my machine". `Format-Table` will pad with spaces to specified width (default is current session's width): could that be it? Using `% {$_.Name}` (`%` = `foreach-object`) rather than format table will avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :) If I use foreach-object everything works fine. The output of ft is right. The problem arises when I pipe to out-file. In this case I have an empty row, then file name, another empty row, filename and so on. I don't know how to check current session's width.

Comment: Thanks for the "whole picture" answer. It comes out -encoding flag is not needed.

Comment: Update. I was running the code from powershell ise editor. If I run it from command line I don't have empty rows except the first line of the file.

Comment: powershell gives me 1 empty row, ise 2:)

Comment: @Przemysław Banaszek. Do you have two empty rows only at the top of the file and no one between each file?

Comment: @nickrulez: Try opening the output file in a text editor and using the end key to show where the end of line is (or [PSCX's](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) `Format-Hex` for a real old school approach). I think you'll see lots of spaces, causing line wrap and thus blank lines. `Format-Table` has a parameter to set the width.

Comment: @rzemysław: see last comment.

Answer (score 3):

Since powershell deals with objects, you need to specify how you want to process each object in the pipe.

This command will get print only the name of each object:

```
dir | ForEach-Object { $_.name }
```

Comment: You forgot to add | Out-File files.txt, but I got that from second answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this great post, but needed it for sub directories as well:

```
DIR /B /S >somefile.txt
```

use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname | Out-File Somefile.txt
```

or the short version:

```
ls | % fullname > somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using:

```
(dir -r).FullName > somefile.txt
```

and with filter for `*.log`:

```
(dir -r *.log).FullName > somefile.txt
```

Note:

```
dir         is equal to `gci` but fits the naming used in cmd
-r          recursive (all subfolders too)
.FullName   is the path only
```