# What is the equivalent of »dir /s /b *foo*.docx« in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am looking for the powershell equivalent for `cmd.exe`'s

```
dir /s /b *foo*.docx
```

I'd like to create an alias (or scriptlet?) for this.

I have found [How do I do 'dir /s /b' in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479663/how-do-i-do-dir-s-b-in-powershell) but with this approach I seem unable to pass the argument `*foo*.docx`.

Comment: `gci -recurse -filter *foo*.docx | select -expandproperty fullname`

Comment: @arco444 that has to be the answer and you should write it up before someone else does. I tested against `-include` just to see and `-filter` was faster.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my comment above, you're looking for:

`gci -recurse -filter *foo*.docx | select -expandproperty fullname`

`gci` or `Get-ChildItem` will return a list of file system objects that match the filter you specified. Each object will have a whole load of information attached with it, but as you're only interested in the path, you can just take the `fullname` property by piping to `select` as shown. The `-expandproperty` flag will ensure the result is returned as a string array rather than a list of objects.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have Powershell 3 or later just do `(dir -recurse -filter *foo*.docx).fullname` (where `dir`, `gci`, `Get-ChildItem`, `ls` are of course interchangeable in any version, just use your favourite).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *foo*.docx | Select-Object FullName | Sort-Object Length
```

Comment: Arco has this answer correct and while he hasnt answered yet I would think it be good form to give him more time. Also the one thing here that does not work is you are returning an object array with a single property instead of a string array which is what the cmd in the OP _sort of_ does.

Comment: Selecting only the fullname property and then sorting on length (which doesn't exist anymore) is not going to work out well.