# How to list all files in a folder (do cmd's `dir /A`) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10, windows-7

In cmd you can run `C:\path> dir /A`, it will list you all the files in a folder (including the hidden `.git/` directory for example).

You can run `dir` in cmd and PowerShell.

You can run `dir /A` in cmd, but can't run `dir /A` in PowerShell. It will complain : [powershell error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxMAW.png)

Similarly, in PowerShell, you can run `PS C:\path> ls` like in Linux bash, but you can't run `ls -a` like in all Linux or `la` like in Ubuntu.

Why is this? I mean why would Microsoft implement things so partially ? So how to list ALL files in a folder in PowerShell, like `dir /A` in cmd or `ls -a` in bash?

And am I experiencing this because I am still running these in Windows 7 or is it the same on Windows 10?

Comment: Try `dir -force`. It is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, not meant to be parameter-compatible.

Comment: @zett42 Yes, I just found out that `dir` and `ls` in PowerShell is actually `Get-ChildItem` from `help dir` and `help ls`. Anyway your solution works, also I think `ls -force` works the same. It's just that I just have to remember at least 3 different ways to do "same thing" in cmd, PowerShell and Linux.

Comment: From : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479663/how-do-i-do-dir-s-b-in-powershell `cmd /r dir /a` also works and possibly many other solutions or hacks. But I don't think that they are great solutions...

Comment: Background reading. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-5.0 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-work-with-file-attributes/

Comment: As for this `It's just that I just have to remember at least 3 different ways to do "same thing" in cmd, PowerShell, and Linux`, why? just avoid cmd.exe, stay in PS always, on Windows/Linux, stick with PS commands. You can always shell out to other executables as needed from PS. See details here: `• PowerShell: Running Executables :     https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx`

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that using `Get-ChildItem -Force` will give you the result of `DIR /A`. While it should not be put into a script, if you are desperate to save keystrokes it is `gci -fo`.

However, it is likely that you want more detail. You can get it using the Attributes member from the System.Io.FileInfo or System.Io.DirectoryInfo object returned by Get-ChildItem and Get-ItemProperty.

```
foreach ($f in [Enum]::GetValues([System.Io.FileAttributes])) { $f }            # attribute ames
foreach ($f in [Enum]::GetValues([System.Io.FileAttributes])) { $f.value__ }    # attribute values

$TheFile = 'C:\src\t.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile | Format-List -Property * -Force   # see all members
```

Test each of the enum attributes using the binary and operator with the Io.FileAttributes enum.

```
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Hidden) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::System) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Directory) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Archive) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Device) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Normal) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Temporary) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::SparseFile) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Compressed) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Offline) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::NotContentIndexed) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::Encrypted) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::IntegrityStream) {'yes'}else{'no'}
if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TheFile).Attributes -band [Io.FileAttributes]::NoScrubData) {'yes'}else{'no'}
```